# unable to see nginx web server in my browser using aws machine public ip?

Tags: linux, nginx, webserver

I have installed an nginx server on an AWS ec2 machine which has public IP of 52.3.218.34.

I have added a DNS entry as well but I am still not sure what is blocking it.

Comment: Has the server been started? If yes what port it is listening on?

Comment: thanks some selinux problem